# Hiding a header using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to hide the header div on my page, but I have already tried using the jquery functions slideup and slidetoggle, as well as hide, but my div does not seem to hide. I actually want it to hide after 5 seconds, but to no avail. Would the css affect the jquery functions of my div?

My Div:

```
<div id="headerrr" class="row firstrow">

<span id="description" >You are currently on preview mode</span>
<span id="close-preview">[close preview]</span>
</div>
```

My CSS:

```
.firstrow{
background-color:#4d4d4d;
color:white;
height:50px;
padding:15px;
}
```

My JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#headerrr").hide().delay(100);
$('#headerrr').slideToggle("slow");
});
```

I am currently using twitter bootstrap 3, would that affect my jquery as well?

Comment: Why this needed `$('#headerrr').slideToggle("slow");`?? it will first hide and then will be slide

Comment: seems fine http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/2xC8E/1

Comment: @dholakiyaankit I placed all of the codes that I used to hide the header.Sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        $("#headerrr").fadeOut();
        // OR $("#headerrr").slideUp();
    },5000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just calling .delay() will not affect the next sequence of commands as it it not equivalent to `Thread.sleep()`

If you want to use a delay then

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#headerrr").hide().delay(1000).queue(function(){
        $(this).slideToggle("slow");
    }).dequeue();
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/2xC8E/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this.... It may be helpful to you....

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#headerrr").hide().delay(1000).queue(function(){
        $(this).slideToggle("slow");
    }).dequeue();
});
```

This is the [FIDDLE document](http://jsfiddle.net/4mzTG/1/)